# Conditional query group by

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to fetch data group by.and remove null value and replace blank.
But its showing one value . this query working but showing result value one and its does not remove value from result. where value is null then i want to show blank.

```
 $userchat= $this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat');
        $users = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
        $this->db->select($userchat.'.chat_to,'.$userchat.'.chat_from,'.$userchat.'.message,'.$userchat.'.created_date,'.$users.'.name,'.$users.'.id as userId,'.$users.'.email,'.$users.'.image,'.$users.'.phone,'.$users.'.country,'.$users.'.company,');
         $this->db->group_by('chat_from'); 
        $this->db->where($userchat.'.chat_from!=1');
        $this->db->from($userchat);
        $this->db->join($users,$users.'.id='.$userchat.'.chat_from');

        //$this->db->order_by($userchat.'.created_date','DESC');
        //$this->db->limit($limit,0);
        $query1 = $this->db->get();
        $usersInfo = $query1->result_array();
         //$sql = $this->db->last_query();
     if(!empty($usersInfo)){
                foreach ($usersInfo as $key=> $users){
                    $userId = $users['userId'];
                    $phone=$users['phone'];
                    $userImage = site_url('assets/profile_image/user_icon.png');
                    $image = $users['image'];
                    if($image != '' && file_exists(DocumentRoot.'assets/profile_image/'.$image)){
                        $userImage = site_url('assets/profile_image/'.$image);
                    }
                    $usersInfo[$key]['image'] = $userImage;
              return $usersInfo;
    }


  }
```

Comment: try using $this->db->group_by($userchat.'chat_from');

Comment: pradeep @ok can you post answer  for remove null value

Comment: use this  $this->db->where($userchat.'.chat_from IS NOT NULL');

Comment: pradeep @any away to  replace value to blank

Comment: what is do mean by replace value to blank

Comment: pradeep@null value show blank

Comment: $this->db->group_by($userchat.'chat_from');@ this query still showing one result need to count

Comment: if you expect null value return you value as NULL it does not return like that it does a blank value

Comment: pradeep 2 @ok got it ,please let me know how can I use grouped by in this query. I have to show only one result by user id

Comment: add this  select also in your query and group by this way

Comment: $this->db->select($userchat.'.chat_from as chat_count');
        $this->db->group_by('chat_count');

Comment: ok grouped by query solved , Thanks

Comment: $this->db->where($userchat.'.chat_from IS NOT NULL');@my phone number is blank, compony name is blank. so how can remove these

Comment: you have to set it in where condition that phone and company is not blank just like $this->db->where($userchat.'.company IS NOT NULL');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$userchat= $this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat');
        $users = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
        $this->db->select('IFNULL('.$userchat.'.chat_to,"") as chat_to,IFNULL('.$userchat.'.chat_from,"") as chat_from,IFNULL('.$userchat.'.message,"") as message,IFNULL('.$userchat.'.created_date,"") as created_date,IFNULL('.$users.'.name,"") as name ,IFNULL('.$users.'.id,"") as userId ,IFNULL('.$users.'.email,"") as email ,IFNULL('.$users.'.image,"") as image ,IFNULL('.$users.'.phone,"") as phone ,IFNULL('.$users.'.country,"") as country,IFNULL('.$users.'.company,"") as company');
         $this->db->group_by('chat_from'); 
        $this->db->where($userchat.'.chat_from!=1');
        $this->db->from($userchat);
        $this->db->join($users,$users.'.id='.$userchat.'.chat_from');

        //$this->db->order_by($userchat.'.created_date','DESC');
        //$this->db->limit($limit,0);
        $query1 = $this->db->get();
        $usersInfo = $query1->result_array();
         //$sql = $this->db->last_query();
     if(!empty($usersInfo)){
                foreach ($usersInfo as $key=> $users){
                    $userId = $users['userId'];
                    $phone=$users['phone'];
                    $userImage = site_url('assets/profile_image/user_icon.png');
                    $image = $users['image'];
                    if($image != '' && file_exists(DocumentRoot.'assets/profile_image/'.$image)){
                        $userImage = site_url('assets/profile_image/'.$image);
                    }
                    $usersInfo[$key]['image'] = $userImage;
              return $usersInfo;
    }
```